# Executing multiple post build commands in CMake depending on condition

Tags: cmake

So I have some cmake definition of `ADD_EXTRA_STEP` that can be either true or false and is set depending on what the user wants. Then, at post build I have to execute a few commands. I currently have something like this:

```
    add_custom_command(TARGET ${some_target}
        POST_BUILD
        COMMAND <command to generate FOO.out>
        COMMAND <command that uses FOO.out and generates FOO2.out>
        COMMENT <some comment>
        VERBATIM
    )
    add_custom_command(TARGET ${some_target}
        POST_BUILD
        COMMAND <some other command>
        COMMENT <some other comment>
        VERBATIM
    )
```

Now in between the two `add_custom_command` I need to execute another command if and only if `ADD_EXTRA_STEP` is set to true. The problem is that for this to work, I need to guarantee that `FOO2.out` exists. My Idea so far is to do something like this:

```
    add_custom_command(TARGET ${some_target}
        POST_BUILD
        COMMAND <command to generate FOO.out>
        COMMAND <command that uses FOO.out and generates FOO2.out>
        COMMENT <some comment>
        VERBATIM
    )
    if(${ADD_EXTRA_STEP})
        add_custom_command(TARGET ${some_target}
            POST_BUILD
            COMMAND <extra step command that uses FOO2.out>
            COMMENT <some extra comment>
            VERBATIM
        )
    endif()
    add_custom_command(TARGET ${some_target}
        POST_BUILD
        COMMAND <some other command>
        COMMENT <some other comment>
        VERBATIM
    )
```

However, I am in doubt whether this would work and whether it is a 'good' practice to implement it in this way. In other words, is it guaranteed that when the command in the `add_custom_command` is executed the command in the previous `add_custom_command` (i.e. the one that generates FOO2.out) will have already executed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12):

You need to combine [add_custom_command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html) with [add_custom_target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html)

The main idea is to use the `OUTPUT` form of the `add_custom_command` on the first step with `OUTPUT` being equal to `FOO2.out` and then specify `FOO2.out` as `DEPENDS` in the conditional target/command. Whether to use `add_custom_command` or `add_custom_target` depends on the actual actions in the command and how the results of the command are used in later steps. Consider this simple example:

```
add_executable(some_executable some_executable_source.c)
add_custom_command(OUTPUT FOO2.out
   DEPENDS some_executable
   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch FOO2.out
   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "creating FOO2.out"
)

if (${ADD_EXTRA_STEP})
  add_custom_target(run ALL
    ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "executing extra step"
    DEPENDS FOO2.out
  )
endif()
```

In this case extra step, if needed, will always be executed after FOO2.out is created

Comment: The problem is that custom target runs twice. During build and during install.